# Deleting blank pages based on size in Adobe with javascript

Tags: javascript, adobe, acrobat

I am trying to delete the blank pages based on size. If it is less than the amount specified the page will be deleted. I keep getting syntax error with this. I looked all over for something similar but cannot find anything.

```
<script>
for (var p=this.pageSize-1; p>=0; p--) {  
    if (this.pageSize-1);  
    for (var n='8kb'; n<this.pageSize-1; n++) {  
        if (this.pageSize(p, n) = '8kb') {  
            this.deletePages(p);  `enter code here`
            break; 
        }
    }  
}  
</script>
```

Comment: if (this.pageSize-1); and (var n='8kb'; n<this.pageSize-1; n++)  and (this.pageSize(p, n) = '8kb') are 3 places to start...

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked up the description of pageSize in the Acrobat JavaScript documentation??

Probably not, because there is no pageSize property in Acrobat JavaScript.

The closest which has something about the size of a page is the various pageBoxes, and they concern the dimensions.

Acrobat JavaScript has only very limited access to the content of a page, and that access is even further limited to text.

HTH.